# Using certificates.cer with NodeJs HTTPS

Tags: ios, node.js, https, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

I have generated a .cer file for IOS push notifications and I would ike to use it with NodeJS HTTPS module.

The only examples I found for HTTPS module work with .pem and .sfx files, not .cer :

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

or 

var options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('server.pfx')
}

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Any solution ?

Comment: did you ever solve this properly? i am stuck at the same place at the moment

Comment: How did you solve this issue please tell us i am stuck on same place...thanks

Comment: @choli have you ever solved this problem?

Comment: @MohitJain did my answer work for you? If not, how did you generate your CSR? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068233/241294)

Answer (score 5):

A `.cer` file can be encoded using two different formats: `PEM` and `DER`.

If your file is encoded using the `PEM` format, you could just use it like any other `.pem` file (more info on that can be found in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options)):

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem", "utf8"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.cer", "utf8")
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello world");
}).listen(8000);
```

If your file's encoded using the `DER` format, you first need convert it to a `.pem` file using OpenSSL (the command was taken from [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)):

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in cert.cer -out cert.pem
```

and then can use the above code with the `cert` filename being `cert.pem` instead of `cert.cer`:

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem", "utf8"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem", "utf8")
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello world");
}).listen(8000);
```

In case you have the the key of the certificate authority that matches your `cert.cer` file, you can include it in the `options` argument of `https.createServer` as following (the code example assumes the file is name `ca.pem` and that it is encoded using the `PEM` format):

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync("ca.pem", "utf8"),
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem", "utf8"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem", "utf8")
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello world");
}).listen(8000);
```

For more information about `https.createServer` and its arguments, check out the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener).

Note: all of the options above assume that you also have a public key encoded in the `PEM` format named `key.pem` and that the `.cer` file is named `cert.cer`. If you don't have a public key, please comment or add it to the question itself and I will update my answer accordingly.

If you're unsure which format your file's encoded in, you could try both options see which one works out for you.

Comment: From where i will get key.pem file. I have only .cer file

Comment: In order to get the .pem file, the .cer file must be signed with your private key. Only when you have the private key you are able to export the certificate (.cer) as a .pem file. If you are not the owner of the certificate, ask the owner to export it for you as a .pem.

Comment: should key.pem not be the 'private' key instead of 'public' ?

Answer (score 3):

HTTPS/TLS encryption is asymmetric, there are two parts to make it work, a **public key** and a **private key**.

The `.cer` file you get from Apple Push Notification Services (APNS) after you have uploaded the certificate signing request (CSR) is the signed **public key**.

The location of the **private key** ***depends on how you generated it***.

If you're on a mac and using the Apple Keychain application, it has the **private key**. Import the `.cer` **public key** back into Keychain. Then use the **Export** option to get a single password protected `.p12` file that will contain both the **private** and **public keys**. See links [[1]](https://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates) and [[2]](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-85e4a917d522).

In your node.js application, the exported `.p12` file and password can be used as the `pfx` and `passphrase` options to [`https.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener).

For example:

```
var options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('./exported-cert.p12'),
  passphrase: 'password-that-was-set-on-export'
};

https.createServer(options, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example using `crt`, you can convert a cer to crt in case it doesn't work:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var fs       = require('fs');
var https    = require('https');

var credentials = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/ssl/certificate.ca-crt", 'utf8'), //certificate concatenation or intermediate certificates
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/ssl/mydomain.com.key", 'utf8'), //SSL key
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/ssl/certificate.crt", 'utf8') //the certificate
};

app.configure(function() {

    // set up your express application

});

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

Taken from here (in spanish): [salvatorelab.es](http://salvatorelab.es/2014/02/certificado-ssl-en-node-js-y-express/)
You can also see examples of what those files (crt, ca-crt...) contain or look like.

Answer (score 2):

@Mohit, You can convert your cer to pem using command below.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

[Source](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)